# Static method not being passed through to another static method

Tags: php

I have created a static method to proccess gets and another to proccess errors via the get

```
class Request
{
public static function get($key)
{
    if (isset($_GET[$key])) {
        return $_GET[$key];
    }
}
}

 class System{
   public static function error($errorid = null) {

        $errors = array(
            1 => 'Product does not exist.',);

        if ($errorid != null && is_numeric($errorid) && isset($errors[$errorid])):
            echo'
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-4 alert alert-danger alert-dismissable">
                    <button aria-hidden="true" data-dismiss="alert" class="close" type="button">×</button>
                     ' . $errors[$errorid] . '
                </div>
                ';
        endif;
    }
}
```

They're both in separate files btw.

I am then initializing it:

```
System::error(Request::get('error'));
```

I have echoed on one page the request, and that shows the get number, but inside the function I have echoed $errorid and it is showing nothing.

Comment: The `$errorid != null` is superfluous, because `is_numeric()` covers that case. If you ever passed in `$errorid = 0`, that would be loosely equal to `null` and break your function, so you should remove it.

Comment: If you get no output from `echo $errorid;` or `var_dump($errorid);` that suggests you may not have error reporting enabled. Always when developing and testing code `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`  I don't see anything that would be in error, but showing errors may reveal something.

Comment: i just copy paste your code and set error=1  in query string and its working ..

Comment: Got error reporting on, var dumped and it equals null. So something else must be breaking it somehow.

Comment: are you sure error value is passed with url..???  `index.php?error=1`